# How to use $_GET['ID'] avoiding ?id=1 with /myid instead

Tags: php, url, get, request

I am trying to find a way to make pages accessible by pure URL using the $_GET[''].

But instead of the following request URL :

http://mywebsite.com/product.php?=1

I want :

http://mywebsite.com/product/1

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: try looking into .htaccess for rewriteURL and you should be through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an PHP - URL-Router and mod_rewrite enabled on your Webserver.

If you're not that experienced you can use a PHP Framework, many Frameworks do have a Good Routing integrated.

Have a Look at some example tutroium: http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/

Comment: You're welcome. Please Tag any answer as the right Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You Should using **Friendly url** in php for creating spec url

you can use this approach:

[how-to-create-dynamic-friendly-urls-using-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410134/how-to-create-dynamic-friendly-urls-using-php)

[how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)

> > please search friendly url in php

Comment: sorry about the loss of feedback, I started working on my project and forgot about stackoverflow since I found the solution. Y, I found a solution based as well on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via url rewriting. Sounds like you want to achieve something like what a lot of PHP frameworks do.

```
 for example http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `htaccess` file at root and write this code in that

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/product.php?id=([0-9]+)$ /product/$1
```

For more detail read about htaccess

If you are checking it at localhost than make sure you have restart your server after writing this code

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2`

> The more number of arguments you enter here that you can access through url

- $1=$2
- $1=$2&$3=$4
- $1=$2&$3=$4&$4=$5

[Your answer is given here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513721/htaccess-mod-rewrite-get-to-variables-with-slashes)